# How to store important data on server side DJANGO

Tags: django, http

I'm writing some Django web site that works with database.

I was wondering how to store important data on server side? For now, I'm storing them in session but is this secure?

Is session cookie?

### UPDATE

Now I have seen on Django web site this sentence:

> It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a session ID – not the data itself

That's all what I need :)

Comment: Your question is very vague. What kind of data are you storing? Django provides different session storage backends with varying degrees of "security" (e.g. cookie-based session backend can expose your stored data, but should still be secure against user tampering as it signs the cookie value).

Answer (score 0):

Django by default uses database-backed sessions, and it is the most [secure engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine).
However, you have to be more precise about what kind of information you are going to store (user-related, site-related etc.)

Answer (score 0):

django as one of the best session secure mechanism because as you've asked session hijacking is very important and common threat but django protects our data through its middleware django.SessionMiddleware plus beside that you can also Session_Secure=True so that your session will travel only through https and not through http adding an extra level of security but still

> do no store any critical data in your sessions